# How to replace the old local file in Spring Integration FTP Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I have a file in remote FTP, say "abc.txt". This file will be updated for every minute. I have configured my FTP Inbound Channel Adapter to retrieve the same file for every minute.

This works fine for the first time (i.e. the local directory is still empty). However, for the 2nd time onward, the intermediate file `abc.txt.writing` cannot replace the original `abc.txt` file. In other words, both the `abc.txt` (old version) and `abc.txt.writing` will coexist in the same directory. (with the new version data). (No error prompt)

Am I hitting a bug or I have to set some parameter such that the old version of file will be deleted first such that the `abc.txt.writing` could be successfully renamed.

```
<bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory"
      p:host="127.0.0.1"
      p:port="21"
      p:username="myusername"
      p:password="mypassword">

<bean id="cachingSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="ftpSessionFactory" />
        <constructor-arg value="1" />
        <property name="sessionWaitTimeout" value="1000" />
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="myChannel"
                                     channel="nullChannel"
                                     session-factory="cachingSessionFactory"
                                     filename-pattern="abc.txt"
                                     remote-directory="/"
                                     preserve-timestamp="true"
                                     local-directory="c:/temp">
    <int:poller cron="15 * * * * ?" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>



c:\temp> dir /a
06/23/2017  11:44 AM           840,000 abc.txt
06/23/2017  11:45 AM           840,000 abc.txt.writing
```

Comment: How about using `int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter` instead of `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter`? Because `int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter` has an attribute `mode="REPLACE"` using which you can get what you desired. The condition is that you should use spring integration version 4.1 or above.

Comment: I am using SI 4.3.10. I am downloading a file from FTP and process it locally in downstream components (I didn't post the process code for the downstream components in the above code snippet). FTP Outbound Channel Adapter doesn't help me for this case.

Comment: Perhaps your downstream code is leaving the old file in-use, preventing the rename operation from succeeding. You could also remove the file in that downstream processing.

Comment: Gary, I have tried to remove the downstream code (I have tested using with the channel changed to nullChannel in ftp:inbound-channel-adapter) but the issue persist. The only way right now is I have to remove the old file after processing (I moved the download file to another directory for processing). But I think it should allow me to overwrite the old file, rather than keep the intermediate .writing file without any error message.

Comment: Originally, I want to use the single directory for download and processing (I will generate the delta content files based on the last image and current image).

Comment: Please, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileWritingMessageHandler` has `deleteSourceFiles` option which is `false` by default. That is for case if you use `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

If you deal with local file somehow other way, e.g. `<service-activator>`, you should consider to use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and perform `File.delete()` on success:

```
<int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpressionString" value="payload.delete()"/>
        </bean>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

Where that `payload` is exactly a local `File` as a result of the `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

Comment: That means in conclusion for you and Gary's advice that I should always delete the downloaded file after processing. The reason that I didn't try this before is I am using the FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter for local filter. It should allow me to keep the old file in local directory, rather than force me to delete the file after processing.

Comment: The filter and directory are not related players. To filter files you don't need directory. But you can't work with files without storing them on the file system. You may consider to use `local-filename-generator-expression` to do something with existing file in some bean.

Comment: But would it be nice that SI FTP Inbound channel adapter will throws exception if the intermediate .writing file failed to rename back to the actual file name (if the actual file name already exists). Currently, it is not easy to spot the problem if silently failed during rename action.

Comment: That's good point and I'm pretty sure it deserves JIRA on the matter. Feel free to raise it btw! But any way that isn't related to your concern which falls to the fact to delete local file anyway.

Comment: Hm. Looking to the code around `preserveTimestamp` I'd say that it is a bug and we have to override `localFile` when the remote file comes with the modifications.Please, really go ahead and raise a JIRA for this use-case: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT

Comment: Artem, FYI, delete the local file is not a workaround solution. The reason is the same file (assume the file in FTP is not yet updated) will be downloaded again in <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter />, but the default FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter restrict the same file message be fired again. This will cause the .writing file failed to rename file again.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. The local `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` doesn't work until after the remote file is copied to the local directory. The `local-filter` is a part of the `FileReadingMessageSource`. So, rename won't fail because there is no local file. But, yes, the `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` might not pass that one because you haven't clear the record for it during removal of the file. So, if you think from the top level application, you should delete file from the local directory and call `ResettableFileListFilter.remove()`, too.

Comment: Sorry Artem, you are correct. As a workaround, I have added an Advice within `<int:poller />` inside `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter />` and delete the local file file inside `beforeReceive()` (if exists). It works properly now. No need to use `ResettableFileListFilter.remove()`